# Python Dict append value if key value pair are same

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I am new to python dict, and have question regarding append value to key. Sample python dictionary is like below. How can I append values if key-value pair, ID & time are same? Please see expected result below. Tried append(), pop(), update(), and couldn't get expected result. Appreciate any help.

```
    {
        "Total": [
            {
                "ID": "ID_1000",
                "time": 1000,
                "name": {
                    "first_name": "John",
                    "last_name": "Brown"
                }
            },
            {
                "ID": "ID_5000",
                "time": 5000,
                "name": {
                    "first_name": "Jason",
                    "last_name": "Willams"
                }
            },
            {
                "ID": "ID_5000",
                "time": 5000,
                "name": {
                    "first_name": "Mary",
                    "last_name": "Jones"
                }
            },
            {
                "ID": "ID_1000",
                "time": 1000,
                "name": {
                    "first_name": "Michael",
                    "last_name": "Kol"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Below is the expected result.

```
    {
        "Total": [
            {
                "ID": "ID_1000",
                "time": 1000,
                "name": [
                    {
                        "first_name": "John",
                        "last_name": "Brown"
                    },
                    {
                        "first_name": "Michael",
                        "last_name": "Kol"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ID": "ID_5000",
                "time": 5000,
                "name": [
                    {
                        "first_name": "Jason",
                        "last_name": "Willams"
                    },
                    {
                        "first_name": "Mary",
                        "last_name": "Jones"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is use a intermediate dictionary with your ids as keys.
Note that this code do not manage the time data, because is not clear if you want to add or what is expected.

```py
import json

values = {
        "Total": [
            {
                "ID": "ID_1000",
                "time": 1000,
                "name": {
                    "first_name": "John",
                    "last_name": "Brown"
                }
            },
            {
                "ID": "ID_5000",
                "time": 5000,
                "name": {
                    "first_name": "Jason",
                    "last_name": "Willams"
                }
            },
            {
                "ID": "ID_5000",
                "time": 5000,
                "name": {
                    "first_name": "Mary",
                    "last_name": "Jones"
                }
            },
            {
                "ID": "ID_1000",
                "time": 1000,
                "name": {
                    "first_name": "Michael",
                    "last_name": "Kol"
                }
            }
        ]
    }

# first create a dictionary with the ids as keys
consolidated_names = {}
for total_value in values["Total"]:
    id = total_value["ID"]
    if id not in consolidated_names:
        consolidated_names[id] = [total_value["name"]]
    else:
        consolidated_names[id].append(total_value["name"])

# then create the structure that you want
processed_values = []
for id in consolidated_names:
    processed_values.append({"ID": id, "name": consolidated_names[id]})


print(json.dumps({"Total": processed_values}, indent=4))
```

Result:

```
{
    "Total": [
        {
            "ID": "ID_1000",
            "name": [
                {
                    "first_name": "John",
                    "last_name": "Brown"
                },
                {
                    "first_name": "Michael",
                    "last_name": "Kol"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ID": "ID_5000",
            "name": [
                {
                    "first_name": "Jason",
                    "last_name": "Willams"
                },
                {
                    "first_name": "Mary",
                    "last_name": "Jones"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```